# Detectar quando um formulário for enviado

Tags: javascript

Como eu poderia detectar quando um formulário é enviado com Javascript puro?
Seria o equivalente a isto em jQuery

```
$('#form').submit(function(event){
  alert('Meu callback');
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Eu estava detectando quando o usuário clica no botão de `submit`, mas relembrei que ele também pode apertar enter por exemplo.

Será que tenho que detectar as duas ações? No caso, quando o usuário clicar em `submit` e quando apertar a tecla enter?

É possível conseguir o efeito apenas verificando se o formulário está sendo enviado?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$('#form').submit(cb)` é um atalho para `$('#form').on("submit", cb)`. Se você quiser evitar o jquery você pode fazer esse bind de eventos usando onsubmit ou o addEventListener.

Para cancelar a submissão da form você pode usar o método preventDefault ou returnar false do event handler:

```
var meuForm = document.getElementById("meuForm");
meuForm.onsubmit = function(){
    if(dadosInvalidos()){
        return false;
    }
}
```

(Vale notar que o  return false pode não ser atingido se a lógica de verificação lançar uma Exception. Veja [essa pergunta no SO em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350247/how-to-prevent-form-from-being-submitted)

Finalmente, usando o evento submit como você está fazendo cobre tanto o caso do usuário clicando no botão quanto o caso dele apertando enter.

Answer (score 4):

Você pode usar o `onsubmit`:

```
<form onsubmit="return minhaFuncao();">

function minhaFuncao()
{
  alert('Minha funcao');
  // Se retornar true deixa a form ser submetida  
  return false;
}
```